# Checking for invalid pointer in deque implementation

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have difficulties checking for a invalid pointer.
I have a `struct` which I want to use as dequeue. It looks like this:

```
struct _dequeue_ {
  struct _dequeue_* next;
  struct _dequeue_* prev;
  int data;
};
typedef struct _dequeue_ dequeue;
```

In my function where I want to push an element to the end of the dequeue I first check if there is already an element, and if not I want to iterate through the list until I find the element which has a null pointer in it's next pointer. However, when my loop reaches the null pointer Visual Studio stops at run time and says `hp was 0xCCCCCCCC` and that it isn't allowed to read there.

Here's the code:

```
void dequeue_push_back(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
    //hp is a pointer to a struct
    //dq** points to the beginning of the list
    if (hp == NULL)
    {
        dequeue OnlyElement;
        OnlyElement.data = data;
        OnlyElement.next = NULL;
        OnlyElement.prev = NULL;
        hp = &OnlyElement;
        dq = &hp;
    }

    else
    {
        while (hp)
        {
            hp = hp->next; //error occurs in this line
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is why this is happening and how can I successfully check for invalid pointers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39983484/edit) to include the details of `hp`, since that's the code that triggers the error?  Is it a global?  A local of `dequeue_push_back`?  Please also add the code that calls `dequeue_push_back`.  Thanks!

Comment: almost certainly hp was not initialized to anything. Since you dont even shows its declaration its hard to say

Comment: Evaluating `(hp)` or `(hp == NULL)` or `(hp != NULL)` in boolean context are all perfectly good ways to check for NULL pointer values.  The null-pointer checks in the code presented use two of these forms; it does not appear that these are inherently problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reference an automatic variable (the `OnlyElement`).

So once the `if (hp == NULL) { }` block finishes, the `hp` pointer is not valid anymore, as the `dequeue` instance is destroyed.

Allocate the `dequeue` on a heap instead, like:

```
dequeue * OnlyElement = malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
OnlyElement->data = data;
OnlyElement->next = NULL;
OnlyElement->prev = NULL;
hp = OnlyElement;
```

---

The `dq` assignment seems wrong too.

You probably wanted this instead:

```
*dq = hp;
```

But your code is not complete, so it's just a guess.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right! I didn't know about automatic variables yet.